# How To read data in xsd file using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xsd

I want read an element from XSD file (i.e.) 10 as shown below,.

`<xs:element name="compId">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>`

Please help me out with a sample.

Answer (score 2):

An XSD file is simply an XML file with a certain namespace - just read it as you would any other XML file.

If you want more detail than that then you will need to be a tad more specific! :-)

Comment: i have created an xml file for that xsd file got the data now